# Using yield WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I might be asking something that's extremely obvious and I have overlooked something, but I'm trying to create a pause before it does something.

I have seen this being used in many places online -

```
yield WaitForSeconds(2);
```

However I get a syntax error of,

> "Error CS1528: Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments
>   in declaration) (CS1528) (Assembly-CSharp)

Which confuses me as im not really sure what `yield` as a keyword really means or does, and im under the assumption that `WaitForSeconds` is a class of its on with the "2" being in the constructor (not in a declaration) any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: "im not really sure what "yield" as a keyword really means or does" - well that would be the first thing to fix. I suggest you find a good C# language book which explains iterator blocks. Trying to code in a language you don't understand is a bad idea, IMO. I've got an article about them) (http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) but a book would go into more detail.

Comment: Thanks that super helpful, will be sure to read up

Comment: The poster refers to pages like these: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is t use an IEnumerator.

```
IEnumerator Example() 
{
    print(Time.time);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    print(Time.time);
}
```

Then you will ask: How do I call this?

```
void Start() 
{
    print("Starting " + Time.time);
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(2.0F));
    print("Before WaitAndPrint Finishes " + Time.time);
}

IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime) 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
}
```

I just read the [link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) Jon Skeet posted on the comments, I too recommend it, it has pretty valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Javascript code for Unity, and try it in the C# language, that´s why you get the error message.

If you click on the C# language selector on a page like http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html
you will get the following example code for C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    IEnumerator Example() {
        print(Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        print(Time.time);
    }
}
```